# xtable kable html output in console

Tags: html, xtable, kable

I am trying to produce some tables using `xtable` and `kable`.

However, the output that comes out in the console shows the `html code` instead of the formatted `html table`, such as

```
<!-- html table generated in R 3.4.1 by xtable 1.8-2 package -->
<!-- Fri Apr 13 02:31:41 2018 -->
<table border=1>
<tr> <th>  </th> <th> outcome_dv_SW </th>
```

Both packages `xtable` and `kable` produced similar type outputs in my console.

I would like to know how I can get the results presented in the correct format (i.e., html) in the console/viewer, and export the results.

Comment: if you install kableExtra and do things like kable(...) %>% kable_styling(). It will be shown in the viewer.

Comment: Thanks @Hao. Do you mind point me to some resources on these tables created from kable can be exported?

Comment: Normally people do it with [rmarkdown](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/).